# MySql ordering problem

Tags: mysql

Consider the situation i have a table name "test"

```
-------
content (varchar(30))
-------
1
abc
2
bcd
-------
```

if i use order by

`Select * from test order by content asc`

i could get result like

```
--------
content
--------
1
2
abc
bcd
---------
```

but is there any way i could get the following result using query

```
--------
content
--------
abc
bcd
1
2
---------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get by the collation, you can do by testing the first character... it appears you want anything starting with a numeric to be after anything alhpa oriented...  something like the ISNUMERIC() representation by Ted, but my quick check doesn't show such function in MySQL..  So an alternative... because numerics in ASCII list are less than "A" (char 65)

```
Select * 
   from test
   order by
      case when left( content, 1 ) < "A" then 2 else 1 end,
      content
```

Although I've seen different CONVERT() calls, I don't have MySQL available to confirm.  However, in addition to the above case/when, you can add a SECOND case/when and call some UDF() or other convert function on the "content" value.  If the string starts as alpha, it should return a zero value so the first case/when will keep them to the top of the list, then since all are all non-convertible to numeric would have a value of zero... no impact on the sort, then finally the content itself which will keep in alpha order.

HOWEVER, if your second case/when / convert function call DOES return a numeric value, then it will be properly sorted within the numeric grouping segment... which will then supercede that of the content... However, if content was something like

```
100 smith rd and 
100 main st
```

they will sort in the same "100" category numeric value, but then alphabetically by the content as

```
100 main st
100 smith rd
```

100

Comment: Thank you DRapp.. it works good.. except for while sorting numbers if we have 1,5,200,30 it sorts like 1,200,30,50(as its varchar type)

Comment: @balanv, updated answer for additional direction for you to try.

Answer (score 2):

this will do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
ORDER BY CAST(field AS UNSIGNED), field ASC
```

Comment: Hey Thanks Brian.. this query is great... and resolves the problem for number sorting too...

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from sometable order by content between '0' and '9', content
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of results is defined by collation used, so if you can find the right collation then yes.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html

//edit

This is tricky. I've done some research and it seems that no currently available collation can do that. However there's also possibility to add new collation to MySQL. [Here's how.](http://forge.mysql.com/w/images/b/b7/HowToAddACollation.pdf)

Comment: ok what collation should i use to achieve the expected result..?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on MySql but on SQL Server you can do this...

```
SELECT * FROM test
ORDER BY IsNumeric(content), content
```